# MySQL Update with Delete sub query

Tags: mysql, database, subquery

I want to do the following

`Delete all the records from a table called survey and then set the status of deleted reference numbers to zero(0) which is in other table`.

The query which I am using is below

```
Update ref_numbers rn SET rn.status = 0 where ref_no IN (DELETE FROM survey WHERE id < 302)
```

But this query is not working, I have also tired to modify the delete query like `DELETE ref_no FROM survey......` but still it's not working. I think I am missing something which i don't know.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't delete and update in the same operation. You can solve this problem better using either (1) a trigger -- maintain the reference count using an AFTER trigger on the child table, or (2) a view -- create the reference count as a correlated subquery in a view of the parent table.

Comment: Ok, the trigger would be AFTER DELETE ?

Comment: After whatever events would lead to a change in the reference count that you want to record. That would probably mean AFTER DELETE and AFTER INSERT. If it's also possible to change the parent of an existing child record (unusual) you would also want AFTER UPDATE.